# How to check if Newman tests fails programmatically?

Tags: continuous-integration, postman, integration-testing, newman

I run postman tests on CI/CD and I need to check whether all tests were successfully passed. I find in the [Newman Docs](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/): `Newman, by default, exits with a status code of 0 if everything runs well, such as without any exceptions`.

If I correctly understand, this code signals, that all tests were passed?
And how I can get this status code programmatically with any console tool?

Comment: how are you running newman using powershell or cmd ?

Comment: I've tried using powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $argument = "run collection.json -e environment.json -k -r cli, htmlextra"
  $process = start-process newman -ArgumentList $argument -PassThru -Wait
 $process.ExitCode
```

Use start process

Comment: Thanks for pushing me in to correct direction. I've little updated your variant and got exit code: 1)  -PassThruu -> -PassThru, 2) $process.ExitCode -> $LASTEXITCODE. Could you please fix these places and I will accept your answer. Could you please provide some variants for the ubuntu console?

Comment: Corrected the first one , lastecitcode and process.exitcode are two different thing

Comment: Process.exitcode gives exit code of process , lastexitcode give latest exit code in the program which can be same if you are not running any other orocess

Comment: That's odd, but $process.ExitCode gives me nothing...

Comment: make sure you have used -Wait

Comment: else it won't wait for process to complete and goes to next line befor process finishes and $process.exitcode might not have anything yet